# How can I publish hexadecimal values?

Tags: ros, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I haven't been able to find this on the ROS wiki:
If I would like to create a publisher for hexadecimal, what type of message would I use? Specifically, I would like to publish this list to the \commands topic:

0x00
0x01
0x1F
0x7F

. I would then write a subscriber to \commands that took the hex values and sent them one by one to a serial port, where my motor controller understood them as motor commands and acted accordingly. I don't think they would publish under int32, would they?

Thanks,

Khiya

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10461/how-can-i-publish-hexadecimal-values?/) by [Khiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/669/khiya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2011-07-06

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could create a custom message that contains:

uint8[] commands

where 'commands' would contain your sequence of bytes.

---

Originally posted by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) with karma: 753 on 2011-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Khiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/669/khiya/) on 2011-07-11**:
Again, thanks you all. It hadn't quite clicked that hex is always just a sort of shorthand for binary. I appreciate your patience!

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-07**:
@Khiya, any number can be hex. It's just a matter of interpreting/printing it that way. It's actually sent across as binary of course. rostopic echo interprets it as a decimal number if it's an int, but you could just as easily print it as hex with `printf( "%x", value );`

**Comment by [Khiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/669/khiya/) on 2011-07-07**:
Thanks a lot then!

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-07-06**:
I don't think you can get much simpler than this.

**Comment by [Khiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/669/khiya/) on 2011-07-06**:
Thanks. So there's no simple way of publishing hex numbers on a ROS topic?